# Python path issue due to multiple versions

Tags: python, path, raspberry-pi, version

I tried to delete an older version of Python off my Raspberry Pi using the command below and didn't do it correctly. I have two other versions of python that I think are causing problems. I have python3 and python3.7.

```
sudo apt-get remove python2.7
```

Now when I enter python into my terminal, I get the error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

Is there a way I can delete everything and just download python again? Or, can I redirect the path to point to python3.7? I tried resetting the path (which I found using the command *whereis python*) using the following code:

```
export PYTHONPATH = /usr/bin/python3.7
```

but, I then got the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I also tried to force remove the broken packages by running the command below and got the following error:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove --reinstreq
```

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 alacarte
 python-sense-hat
 python-pyflakes
 gyp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help! I can't live without Python lol.

Comment: How did you delete it?

Comment: I used sudo apt-get remove python2.7

Comment: what is the output of `which python3`, `which python` and `which python3.7` ?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3.7`

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin | grep python` ? trying to see what the symlinks are for each of those bin

Comment: I would see if there aren't any programs in rasbian that depend on python2. Why were you trying to delete python2.7 ?

Comment: I thought that deleting python2.7 would make the path redirect to the newer versions. I was trying to use a library that requred python3 or higher. And, yes I think the problem is related to rasbian dependencies.

Comment: I suggest you reinstall python2.7, usually python dependencies can be corrected without deleting prior version of python (especially python2.7). Just try adding a symlink with `ln -ls` to python3.x as python in /usr/bin, and do the same for pip (if pip is for python2 then add a symlink for pip to pip3). In case you're unsure of the install of a module (on which python) using pip, usually i make sure by running `python3.x -m pip install <module>`